# JOOQ update set not populating values

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, jooq

In a Spring Boot application, I am using JOOQ to build SQL which is then being executed through JdbcTemplate. I am not using codegen or executing queries with JOOQ. The problem I have run into is with doing an Update. I'm using `table()` and `field()` as static imports from org.jooq.impl.DSL. The table is declared at the top of the class like this:

```
private final Table<Record> TABLE = table("rjri.participant");
```

Here is the String representation of the object I am using to update:

```
Participant{id='10',{ firstName='Jacob', lastName='Nerney', dateOfBirth='1985-01-14T20:51:39', address='1662 Ryan Ave', city='Murray', state='KY', zip='420711234', phoneNumber='2702274322', email='nern@mail.com'}}
```

Here is the JOOQ code I am using to build the update statement:

```
final String sql = dslContext.update(TABLE)
            .set(field("first_name"), participant.getFirstName())
            .set(field("last_name"), participant.getLastName())
            .set(field("date_of_birth"),
                    DateTimeFormatter.toDateTimeString(participant.getDateOfBirth()))
            .set(field("address"), participant.getAddress())
            .set(field("city"), participant.getCity())
            .set(field("state"), participant.getState()).set(field("zip"), participant.getZip())
            .set(field("phone"), participant.getPhoneNumber())
            .set(field("email"), participant.getEmail())
            .set(field("modified_date"),
                    DateTimeFormatter.toDateTimeString(LocalDateTime.now()))
            .where("id = " + participant.getId()).getSQL();
```

But, when I run this code, the SQL being produced is this:

```
update rjri.participant set first_name = ?, last_name = ?, date_of_birth = ?, address = ?, city = ?, state = ?, zip = ?, phone = ?, email = ?, modified_date = ? where (id = 10)
```

I cannot figure out why the values are not being populated. Save me!

Comment: *".where("id = " + participant.getId())"* - don't do that! [You're creating a SQL injection vulnerability despite using jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/05/using-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-to-dump-your-database/). Other than that, what benefit are you getting from 1) not using the code generator and 2) not running the query through jOOQ?

Comment: fortunately, we are validating that id field in a different place, so we are taking precautions in using that `where()` the way we do. i would actually be fine with using the codegen and use jooq for execution as well, but my team lead is actually more inclined to just drop jooq altogether if we run into issues with it. i pushed for us to at least use the dsl for writing queries. i mean, this guy is opposed to using lombok because it adds a build dependency; seems to be really adverse to codegen in general.

Comment: I must insist, never rely on such an external precaution. That precaution may disappear and your vulnerability is out in the open. Write `where("id = ?", participant.getId())` instead. Tell "this guy" that he's wrong :) Code generation is a great thing. Optimisers generate complex algorithms from SQL, the javac generates byte code from Java source code, and the JIT generates machine code from byte code. Ask him if he'd rather do all of that himself.

Comment: thank you. i'm going through and fixing some of this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Query.getSQL(ParamType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL-org.jooq.conf.ParamType-) method to force jOOQ to inline all bind variables. But quite likely, you will be better off to use a prepared statement for performance reasons, in case of which you should both extract the SQL string using [`Query.getSQL()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL--) and the bind variables using [`Query.getBindValues()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getBindValues--).